# local variable 'urllib' referenced before assignment even though I imported it

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

Using python 3.4, I can't find out whats wrong with this. I've looked at other websites & threads where people are having the same issue but their solutions don't help me.

```
import urllib,urllib.parse,urllib.request,random

try:
    if len(args)>20: room.message("Your username can't be more than 20 letters!")
    else:
        if "<i><font color=#000000>{0}</font></i> is not (yet) a registered Chatango name!<br/><br/>".format(args) in str(urllib.request.urlopen("http://{0}.chatango.com/".format(args)).read().decode()):
            try:
                rand = (' '.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters+string.digits+'~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?') for i in range(random.randint(8,20)))).replace(' ','')
                dat = urllib.parse.urlencode({
                    "email": ("usr"+str(random.randint(100,10000))+"@duubz.bot"),
                    "login": args,
                    "password": rand, "password_confirm": rand,
                    "checkerrors": "yes"
                    }).encode()
                resp = urllib.request.urlopen("http://chatango.com/signupdir", dat)
                headers = resp.headers
                room.message('Private messaging you your password for {0}, {1}.'.format(args,user.name.capitalize()))
                self.pm.message(ch.User(user.name), 'Your password for the account {0} is: {1}'.format(args,rand))
            except Exception as e: room.message( str(e) )
        else: room.message("{0} is already a username.".format(args.upper()))
except Exception as e: room.message( str(e))
```

Comment: for some reason, when I paste the code into the post, the indents get screwed up. I'll try an fix it right now.

Comment: EDIT: indentation is fixed

Comment: Is this code within a function, or something? If you ran this from the top level of a module, I don't think you'd get an error about local variables, since there are none at module level (local variables are the module's global variables. Also, can you post the full traceback?

Comment: you code should not produce the error. [Create the shortest program that demonstrates the issue and post the full traceback](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
from urllib import (parse, request)
```

Then just use:

```
resp = request.urlopen("http://chatango.com/signupdir", dat)
```

And fix all those indents!